# C# - Owin Oauth doesn't redirect to external login page

Tags: c#, facebook, owin, identity

Today i tried to implement external facebook login on my project.
But when i try to login calling the method of ExternalLogin, this method does not return to Facebook login page

I tried to do this:
https://coding.abel.nu/2014/06/understanding-the-owin-external-authentication-pipeline/

And when i see my context the AuthenticationResponseChallenge is null.

Follow the code:

Startup.Auth.cs

```
     app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        var fao = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AppId = APP_ID_FACEBOOK, //on Web.config
            AppSecret = APP_SECRET_FACEBOOK //on Web.config
        };

        fao.Scope.Add("email");
        fao.Scope.Add("basic_info");

        fao.Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
        {
            OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:facebook:access_token", context.AccessToken, XmlSchemaString, "Facebook"));
                foreach (var x in context.User)
                {
                    var claimType = string.Format("urn:facebook:{0}", x.Key);
                    string claimValue = x.Value.ToString();
                    if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimType, claimValue, XmlSchemaString, "Facebook"));

                }
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        };

        fao.SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie;
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(fao);
```

AccountController.cs

```
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {

        var result = new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Conta", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        return result;
    }


    private const string XsrfKey = "XsrfId";

    internal class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
    {
        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri)
            : this(provider, redirectUri, null)
        {
        }

        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId)
        {
            LoginProvider = provider;
            RedirectUri = redirectUri;
            UserId = userId;
        }

        public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
        public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
            if (UserId != null)
            {
                properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
            }

            context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
        }
    }
```

I tried to create an empty project with my facebook app credentials and worked fine, but in this project this don't work

Anybody can help me?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Can you expound that?

Comment: The challenger don't create the url to login on facebook and the response of ExternalLogin is 302 and empty

Answer (score 1):

After a day, i found the solution

My webconfig was with

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
</authentication>
```

When i changed to

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

The challeger started to redirect to facebook login after submit the form.

Comment: Good find. I had the same problem. Thank you.